# vds, ipv6 - "отдать" адрес клиенту за adsl модемом

Tags: ip, vpn, proxy, ipv6, linux

Добрый день,

тема с ipv6 для меня совсем неведома, посему не постесняюсь задать глупые вопросы тут.Суть такая имеем vds (centos5.6, один сетевой интерфейс ipv4 + ipv6 адрес). Есть возможность купить еще N ipv6 адресов, как я понимаю они также повиснут на этом интерфейсе.

Я хочу купить еще 1 адрес и каким-то образом "отдать" его домашней windows машине. Которая ходит в инет через ADSL (ростелеком, при выход в инет дается белый ip). Само железо (adsl модем) ipv6 не понимает ни каким образом. Каким образом это можно сделать? т.е. интересует сама технология - пока думаю лишь в сторону openvpn), или иной туннель какойто (какой?)

Интересует сейчас только теория и вообще сама возможность.

p.s. да я знаю о teredo, 6to4б и прочих gogoNet..

Comment: Ты хочешь что бы win машина в инет ходила с 6-ым адресом?

Comment: в общем, да. Но именно с адресом "выданным" vds

Comment: МММ.... Можно так, туннель между хостом и сервером, на сервере какойнить прокси,  на хосте в приложении указываешь адрес прокси через туннель. Без прокси не получится, так как на хосте придется менять default route что в итоге приведет к потери инета.

Comment: А для чего?1. Много чего все еще не поддерживает IPv62. Использовать все его преимущества тоже нет смысла/возможности ибо упакован он будет в ppp.

Answer (score 1):

Часто хостер даёт возможно поднять VPN к vds машине, использую IPSec PSK ключ.После поднятия VPN у вас будет Ipv4 Ipv6 адрес такой же как и у VDS - ну или другой свободный - какой выдадут.Узнаейте о такой возможности.

Answer (score 1):

в таком случае попробуй http://www.gogo6.com/ в журнале ХакКкер была такая статья что бы получит ipv6 на халяву с доступом во внешний мир